# Vagrant/virtualbox no SSH connection and timeout (Windows)

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, nat

I a trying to setup this machine: https://github.com/ByteInternet/hypernode-vagrant

When I do `vagrant up` i get following error: `Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot.`

Full context of the error:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'hypernode' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> hypernode: Will use PHP 7. If you want PHP 5.5 instead change the php version in local.yml.
==> hypernode: Checking if box 'hypernode_php7' is up to date...
==> hypernode: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> hypernode: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> hypernode: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
hypernode: Adapter 1: nat
hypernode: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> hypernode: Forwarding ports...
hypernode: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
hypernode: 3306 (guest) => 3307 (host) (adapter 1)
hypernode: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> hypernode: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> hypernode: Booting VM...
==> hypernode: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
hypernode: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
hypernode: SSH username: vagrant
hypernode: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

When I boot the VM manually, I can see the networking is not working as it should be. There is no connection. When I change the VM's settings to bridged network the networking does work. But the vagrant is configured as NAT. So any changes I make in the settings or in the vagrant file seem to be resetting back.

I tried Vagrant 1.9.3, 1.9.2 and 1.9.0 on two different PC's. I am using Virtualbox 5.1.18. When I **filter** down the logs with "NAT" is see following errors **(this is not the complete log, only a small portion)**:

```
00:00:00.575454 SUP: Loaded VMMR0.r0 (C:\Program     Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VMMR0.r0) at 0xfffff80c897b0000 - ModuleInit at     fffff80c897d3590 and ModuleTerm at fffff80c897d3a80 using the native ring-0 loader
00:00:01.681747 Driver = "NAT" (cb=4)
00:00:01.962037 SUP: Loaded VBoxDDR0.r0 (C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxDDR0.r0) at 0xfffff80c898d0000 - ModuleInit at         0000000000000000 and ModuleTerm at 0000000000000000 using the native ring-0 loader
00:00:02.196495 NAT: Guest address guess set to 10.0.2.15 by initialization
00:00:02.204465 NAT: DNS#0: 192.168.178.1
00:00:02.271317 NAT: Failed to redirect TCP 127.0.0.1:2222 -> 0.0.0.0:22 (Unknown error)
00:00:02.271732 NAT: Failed to redirect TCP 0.0.0.0:3307 -> 0.0.0.0:3306 (Unknown error)
00:00:02.272033 NAT: Failed to redirect TCP 0.0.0.0:2200 -> 0.0.0.0:80 (Unknown error)
00:00:09.976199 NAT: Link up
00:00:39.428974 NAT: DHCP offered IP address 10.0.2.15
00:00:39.429404 NAT: DHCP offered IP address 10.0.2.15
00:03:02.167191 NAT: DHCP offered IP address 10.0.2.15
00:03:02.167820 NAT: DHCP offered IP address 10.0.2.15
00:07:58.531621 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_cluster, used:0)
00:07:58.532221 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_packet, used:0)
00:07:58.532232 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf, used:1)
00:07:58.532419 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_pagesize, used:0)
00:07:58.532961 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_9k, used:0)
00:07:58.533255 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_16k, used:0)
00:07:58.533424 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_ext_refcnt, used:0)
00:07:58.536529 Changing the VM state from 'DESTROYING' to 'TERMINATED'
```

How can I solve or debug this?

**UPDATE**

Last couple of days I also retried with different version of virtualbox and Vagrant listed below without any results:

- Virtualbox 5.0.18
- Virtualbox 5.0.20
- Virtualbox 5.0.36
- Vagrant 1.9.3

I also tried another box, which has the same problem. So it seems it's not the box but the host.

Furthermore I tried a setup on a Windows 7 machine with exactly the same results. I think I am missing something in the configuration but I don't know what since there is not a definitive guide to get this working on a Windows machine.

**UPDATE 2:** Could it be possible the machines I try this on do not support this kind of a setup? I tried looking for virtualizations options in the BIOS.

**UPDATE 3:** When I do `ssh -v 127.0.0.1 -p 1222` from my host to the guest I get following error. SSH service is up and running on the guest. I checked with `sshd service status`.

```
$ ssh -v 127.0.0.1 -p 1222
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 1222.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 1222: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 1222: Connection refused
```

**UPDATE 4:** I cannot ping any internet IP's or domains from the guest machine.

**UPDATE 5:** SOLVED! Switched to Linux for quite a while now. Best decision ever :D

Answer (score 2):

First of al, changing the first interface to NAT is normal behavior. It's a requirement in order to make vagrant work.

You can check two things:
1) preferences > network > nat-network. (settings should be like this):

[network settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGiQp.png)

2) make sure you're virtual cable is connected

[cable connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xkhn.png)

3) maybe you can try another vagrant box.

Comment: Mine is configured to use "NAT" see: http://imgur.com/CAt5LPq.png. There is also an option "NAT-network". But if i switch to that 'vagrant up' gives errors. My second nic is also configured. Like this http://imgur.com/JP8qWCu.png. I did not try another vagrant box yet. But I know this one is working. My co-worker got it working in his Linux machine. Btw, the warning in the screenshots is about the machine using too much ram. Nothing to do with the networking.

Answer (score 0):

When I have this error on Windows 10 Pro:

```
    ...
    homestead: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. ...
...
```

I have found that all I need to do is have the **VirtualBox GUI open** and the **VM selected** while running this on a command line:

`vagrant reload --provision`

If the GUI is closed, it repeatedly times out that throws the error above.

If the GUI is opened, then the process continues as normal with no errors, and everything starts working.

I have also found that sometimes after automatic Windows restarts, my network adapter does not have the `VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver` installed, and that can also cause this error.

This can be fixed by opening the network connection properties and clicking `Install -> Service -> Oracle Corporation -> VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver` to install the driver.

[image: Windows 10 NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver installation dialogs]

It should just appear in the list without having to go through a driver install, but if you somehow never had that driver installed before, then this might put you through a driver install process.

On Windows, the typical path to the folder with that driver in it is below. You probably won't have to manually install anything, but in case you do, open that folder and then `Right-Click -> Install` the **VBoxNetFlt.inf** file.

`%ProgramFiles%\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\network\netflt`